# Is there a way to detect if a piece of JavaScript code is being executed in a touch handler?

Tags: javascript

Title pretty much says it all. To work around a Safari/iOS limitation concerning audio playback, I would like to find out if my code is being executed as part of a touch-related event (e.g. `touchstart`, when the user presses a button).

Is there a way for a piece of JavaScript code to determine if the "call context" is a touch event?

Example:

```
// application code
window.addEventListener("touchstart", myTouchHandler);

function myTouchHandler(event) {
   thirdPartyLib.doSomething();
   return false;
}

// library code
function doSomething() {
   var isTouch = ... // how to know if doSomething() is invoked in a touch handler?
}
```

Comment: Aren't you registering an event handler _to the touchstart event_? So you know if the `event.type.includes( 'touch'  )` it's a touch. Or if `event.touches` exists (aka `'touches' in event`...

Comment: @somethinghere in case I register a handler myself, then of course I know that I'm being executed in touch handler. But in my case I have a library function that I'm offering to an application, and depending on it being invoked in a touch event or not it will do different things.

Comment: Ah in that case, you might just want to try `window.matchMedia( 'pointer:coarse' ).matches` in order to figure out what kind of event you are likely to get.

Comment: I have been thinking about this for a bit and I don't think you can. This would require a trace output to be readable in javascript - which it isn't. I also though about using a Proxy to see what handlers register to addEventListeners touch events, but since you can't actually determine whether it calls one of your libraries methods inside of it, that's not particularly useful either. The problem I have is: what are you trying to accomplish? Why would you _need_ to know whether something is triggered by a certain event? You could just require your methods to pass in events when called.